# Angular JS comment directive does not function properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The following code does not seem to print the text out from the directive defined:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

    <!-- directive: devComment -->

</div>


<script>
    app.directive("devComment", function(){
                return{

                    restrict : "M",
                    replace : true,
                    template : " A comment made this print to html "

                };
            });
</script>
```

Comment: I'd strongly discourage using comment directives, they don't seem to obey the normal AngularJS directive naming rules. You also need to use `replace` which is a deprecated property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just got the wrong format for the directive name within your template. It should be

```
<!-- directive: dev-comment -->
```

*(ed: actually, I just tested this and for comment directives, the name normalisation does not seem to happen so the real problem was no root element)*

In order to use `replace`, you must also have exactly one root element in your template.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('devComment', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'M',
    replace: true,
    template: '<span>A comment made this print to html</span>'
  };
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <!-- directive: dev-comment -->
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: @jack yeah, I missed the bit about requiring a single root element. Fixed it up with a code runnable example too. If OP were using the right directive name though, they would have gotten a console error.

Answer (score 1):

Your template must have exactly one root element.Please check the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt?p0=devComment&p1=).So your template should be like below

```
template : " <p>A comment made this print to html</p> "
```

Working plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/tBbjeVbdaq4sAYj7xZBg?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <!-- directive: dev-comment -->
</div>
<script>
    app.directive("devComment", function(){
                return{
                    restrict : "M",
                    replace : true,
                    template : "<h3>A comment made this print to html</h3> "
                };
            });
</script>
```

Comment: The name of the directive specified in the directive method must be camel case and must start with a lower-case letter.                                            Ex: The directive's name myCustomDir becomes my-custom-dir in HTML. myCustomDir is called normalized directive name